# Create new top-level backlog in Azure Devops through Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I’ve been writing a Python script that uses Azure DevOps REST API to automate some steps in regards to the creation of a organization in Azure DevOps.

One of the steps includes creating four new backlog levels, but I don’t seem to find any endpoint in the API that could help me with that task.

For reference, I’m trying to reproduce the steps shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops

More specifically, in the “Add a portfolio backlog” part of the document.

Can anybody help me? I'm editing through repl.it and using the requests library, if that's helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One of the steps includes creating four new backlog levels, but I don’t seem to find any endpoint in the API that could help me with that task.

To meet your requirement, you can use the following Rest API:[Behaviors - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/behaviors/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to add the New Backlog levels.

**Rest API:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/behaviors?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "inherits":"System.PortfolioBacklogBehavior",
    "name":"backloglevelname",
    "referenceName":null,
    "color": "009CDD"
}
```

Then it will create new backlog level in Process. You can record the **referenceName** in the Rest API response

**Result:**

[image]

If you need to add the work item type to the new Backlog level, you can use the following Rest API:

**Rest API:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/work/processes/{ProcessID}/workItemTypesBehaviors/{processname.workitemtype}/behaviors?api-version=5.0
```

**Request Body:**

```
{"behavior":{"id":"referenceName"},"isDefault":true}
```

Refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the Process ID.